# How to make a limited size page-spanning background in html/css

Tags: html, css

I am a self taught coder developing a website for a nonprofit I've founded, and would like to have a footer to thank the sponsors of said nonprofit. I'm trying to distinguish this section from the rest of the site by changing its background color relative to the rest of my webpage. I've tried everything I can think of, like creating a div/footer with a width of 100% and a different background-color, but that only adds background colors to the portions of the div that contain text (the text appears to be highlighted with this color, rather than the color being a solid background applied to the entire div). All of my research has only turned up results for either how to make the entire background of a page a specific color, or how to add styles to horizontal rules, neither of which help me (the former because I want the color to differ from that of the rest of the page, and the latter because I am unable to put the content/text I would like to include over it). If anyone could help, it would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: Clarification has been requested. Essentially, I was creating a footer for my website that I wanted to look like the one [here](http://detroitsoup.com/) with that black bar at the bottom that spans the page. My issue was that the div I was creating didn't span the page well enough to make it a solid bar; it was more of a blocky coloring that only showed up in nested divs containing text. I posted this question because I wasn't able to find any guides on how to span the page with a footer like this, but adding a nested div with the color background I wanted and a width of 100vm, setting the margins to 0, and hiding overflow ultimately let me accomplish my intent. Hopefully this is adequate clarification. I'd also appreciate if the downvote I accrued were removed, or at least explained; it's difficult to improve my posts if I don't know the issue with them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of hard to tell what the exact issue is without a visual example of your issue. But from the sounds of it, you want the background to extend the entire width of the page, but don't want the actual content to extend the entire width.

To do this, I would introduce a class that represents the width you want your content to be, and put that class nested within the footer (and any other elements on the page) where you want the parent (ie, the footer) to extend the width of the page, and everything inside the footer to be contained within the width that you want the content to be displayed. Here is an example, where the class I"m referring to is `.viewport`. Assigning a background to your `footer` and nesting `.viewport` within the `footer` will give the footer a full-width background, while leaving the text nested within the footer at your specified width.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  background: #eee;
}
.viewport {
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}
footer {
  background: #171717;
  color: #fff;
}
.section {
  padding: 2em 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="section">
  <h1 class="viewport">
    This is a header
  </h1>
</header>
<main class="section">
  <div class="viewport">
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
  </div>
</main>
<footer class="section">
  <p class="viewport">This is a footer</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Out of curiosity, why was .viewport given a width of 90% instead of 100%? It doesn't seem like that'd span the page, but it works

Comment: @Bugsy because that's the element that wraps the page content. If it were 100%, the content would butt up against the sides of the browser once you get < 960px and that looks bad, but you can put whatever you want there. I just used 960px/90% as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick fix for you:

HTML

```
<div class="Footer">
  <div class="Content">Place you stuff here</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.Footer{position:relative; width:100%; height:100px; display:block; float:left; background-color:RED;}
.Footer > .Content{position:relative; margin:auto; width:80%; height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest solution is  with bootstrap but since you didnt  mention it that means you are not using it.

```
<footer>
    <div class="sponsors">
        Type anything you want 
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
.sponsors{
text-align:center;
background-color:(your color);

}
```

This should work, if not tell me what went wrong!

Comment: Thanks! I think my problem was that I added .sponsors directly to the footer, rather than having a contained div.